# SQL - Averaging each second row

Tags: sql-server, group-by, average

I have two tables which contain half-hour data and I would like to take the average of the two half-hours to see an hourly average.

My table look like this:

```
Date(date)       HalfHour(int)      Value(dec(18,3))
2018-04-17           1                  50
2018-04-17           2                  100
....
2018-04-17           47                 100
2018-04-17           48                 200
```

I want to a query which can return this:

```
Date(date)       Hour(int)      Value(dec(18,3))
2018-04-17           1                  75
....
2018-04-17           24                 150
```

There is an ID column, but it can't be used for this purpose because it has gasp and therefore is consistent.

And I know I have to use a group by function but haven't been able to figure out how.

Comment: group by halfHour/2 (or something along those lines)

Comment: Please mark as answered, If satisfied with the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps...

```
SELECT [date]
       (HalfHour + 1) / 2 AS [Hour], --This ASSUMES HalfHour is the datatype int, due to integer maths
       AVG([Value]) As [Value]
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY [Date],       
         (HalfHour + 1) / 2;
```

Comment: Worked well! Thanks!

Comment: Just so I understand what is going on in the query. We have 48 half hours and we are converting them to 24 by using the calculation: (HalfHour +1) / 2. But for example the value for half 2 would be = (2+1)/2 = 1,5, which is not an integer. Shouldn't I get an error message saying "Unable to convert 1,5 to data type int"? - what is it in the query that throws all not integer value away?

Comment: @Deldar22 In SQL Server, when dealing with an integers **only** any equation will result in an integer. This means that `(2+1) /2 =  3 / 2 = 1`. The `.5` is lost, as you're using an integer. If , however, you were to change the equation to `(2 + 1.0) / 2`, because you're not *only* dealing with integers, the result would be `1.500000`. This is because Decimals have a higher data precedence in SQL Server than an integer.